# Link submitted form bypasses onsubmit return confirm message

Tags: javascript, html

I have a test HTML form:

```
    <form action="?test" method="post" name="test_form" 
        onsubmit="return confirm('Submit form, are you sure?')">
    </form>
```

And I want to submit it via a link:

```
<a href='#' onclick='document.test_form.submit(); return false;'>Submit form</a>;
```

The link submits the form, but bypasses the onsubmit return confirm message, but if I use a submit button instead then it will display the message. How do I get the message to display when using the link to submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your confirmation in the link's `onclick` handler (although, of course, it would be better to actually have an event handler function and use `addEventListener()`).

```
<a href='#' onclick='confirm("Submit form, are you sure?") && document.test_form.submit(); return false'>Submit form</a>
```